# BBcode parser, how to attach to main page

Tags: php, html, parsing, bbcode

I am trying to use this simple BBcode parser shown below, but I am not sure how to actually make it work on my webpage. I have used previously some lines which have used some functions that are not recognised. Such as:

```
require_once('parser.php'); // path to Recruiting Parsers' file
$parser = new parser; //  start up Recruiting Parsers
$parsed = $parser-> p($mytext); // p() is function which parses
```

Where the p() function is not recognised and hence, nothing is parsed. I am using a text editor but it outputs bbcode, which I am trying to convert back into html. Do you know what code I should use so that it would parse? I am not a developer so this is all very strange.

```
Here is the perser.php:

<?php
function bbcodeParser($bbcode){
/* bbCode Parser
*Syntax: bbcodeParser(bbcode)
*/

/* Matching codes */
$urlmatch = "([a-zA-Z]+[:\/\/]+[A-Za-z0-9\-_]+\\.+[A-Za-z0-9\.\/%&=\?\-_]+)";

/* Basically remove HTML tag's functionality */
$bbcode = htmlspecialchars($bbcode);

/* Replace "special character" with it's unicode equivilant */
$match["special"] = "/\�/s";
$replace["special"] = '&#65533;';

/* Bold text */
$match["b"] = "/\[b\](.*?)\[\/b\]/is";
$replace["b"] = "<b>$1</b>";

/*many other properties as before: italics, colours, fonts etc.*/

/* Parse */
$bbcode = preg_replace($match, $replace, $bbcode);

/* New line to <br> tag */
$bbcode=nl2br($bbcode);

/* Code blocks - Need to specially remove breaks */
function pre_special($matches)
{
    $prep = preg_replace("/\<br \/\>/","",$matches[1]);
    return "�<pre>$prep</pre>�";
}
$bbcode = preg_replace_callback("/\[code\](.*?)\[\/code\]/ism","pre_special",$bbcode);


/* Remove <br> tags before quotes and code blocks */
$bbcode=str_replace("�<br />","",$bbcode);
$bbcode=str_replace("�","",$bbcode); //Clean up any special characters that got     misplaced...

/* Return parsed contents */
return $bbcode;
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried replacing your `p()` function with `bbcodeParser()`? Looks like if you do this, it should work as expected:

```
require_once('parser.php'); // path to Recruiting Parsers' file
$parsed = bbcodeParser($mytext); // bbcodeParser() is function which parses
```

Comment: I get an error: Fatal error: Call to undefined function bbcodeParser()

Comment: Why is it not recognising these functions..?

Comment: then you have something else in your parser.php file than what you posted, see here, the for a full working example: http://codepad.org/QXOGAFha

Comment: Okay, I can get it to work on its own, you are correct. But when I try to use it to change code that it coming from the sql database, it shows me this 

    Text<br />
    <br />
    &lt;b&gt;moretext&lt;/b&gt;

when its suppose to be
 
text 
**moretext**

This is getting outof control. I have no idea what is going on and all I want is for this stupid editor to work...arrrrr

Comment: how is that text stored in a database? you might want to look for `htmlspecialchars()` or `htmlentities()` functions in your code, as those would be normally responsible for converting those characters into what you're seeing

Comment: Hmm, I had a search but did not see them. Basically I am trying to use a SCEditor, which seems to send the text off in BBcode. The guy who wrote the editor code said it could be that the site is trying to prevent XSS attacks and therefore not letting html code be edited, so it just seems to send the code to the database in BBcode.. he said I could try using  html_entity_decode(), which didn't work, or then converting the text into html, which I am trying to do! I understood it is better to convert it after it comes back from the database rather than when it goes there.

Comment: so, what I'd do would be to output both - the raw DB text and a parsed one line after line, like so: `echo $mytext; echo bbcodeParser($mytext);` - if you get those escaped HTML characters even before calling `bbcodeParser` function, the problem could lie somewhere where the text is actually being retrieved from DB, otherwise the problem would be probably in *parser.php*

Comment: So I got this:
 TEXT
[b]text[/b]

TEXT<br />
text<br />
<br />  so the text coming from the DB is in bbcode and the parse file does convert it, but the page does not recognise it as html, or something.

Comment: This is what I'm using to get the text, after connecting to the DB: `$sqlCommand = "SELECT srti FROM table WHERE showing='1' AND name='text1' LIMIT 1"; 
$query = mysqli_query($myConnection, $sqlCommand) or die (mysqli_error($myConnection)); 
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) { 
    $text1 = $row["stri"];
} 
mysqli_free_result($query); `

Comment: The last option here is to check for the output path - if you're showing this on page, check where is that conversion occurring by echoing the text in different places in your code. If you're feeding this back into the editor, there might be an editor setting preventing use of HTML inside it. Other than this, I'm outta ideas ;-P

Comment: Well now I did some extra tests on a separate php file, stripping everything unnecessary, and it seems to actually follow the <b> tag, so that the text is bold, but it displays <br /> signs, where a break should be. How can it work for some but not the others, I'll maybe see if adding the break sign into the parse file helps, eventhough it seems to be in html..